# como usar o plugin isotope em 2 grid distintas

Tags: html, jquery, plugin

como eu posso usar o plugin do `isotope` em duas `grids` distintas. por exemplo eu estou utilizando `tabs` do `bootstrap` na minha primeira `tab` eu tenho o primeiro carregamento da grid e na ultima `tab` eu tenho o ultimo carregamento da `grid`. porem não consigo fazer as duas funcionarem simultaneamente ele carrega somente minha primeira `grid` com os efeitos do `isotope` e minha segunda `grid` ele não carrega com os efeitos, ele apenas carrega se eu abrir o modo desenvolvedor do `chrome`. alguém sabe como posso utilizar isso simultaneamente?

meu codigo js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if ($.find('.gridlayout').length) {
      $('.gridlayout').isotope({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-item'
          }
      });
    }
};
```

meu codigo html:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="m_tabs_6_4" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="col-xl-12">         
      <div class="gridlayout-main">
        <div class="gridlayout1">
          <div class="grid-item">                           
            <img class="img-responsive" alt="gallery-image" src="caminho da img">
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```